# Mysql Query SUM dynamic amounts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I need help writing a mysql query to SUM amounts in a column where another columns values may be different depending on the value that it contains.  Here is an example of my table.

```
account     type         amount
-------     ----         ------
Dell        Inventory    500.00
Microsoft   Inventory    100.00
Cisco       Inventory    300.00
Dell        Inventory    400.00
Webhosting  Service       15.00
```

Here is what I have so far, its not much but I can't think of a good way to do this.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = 'Inventory'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  Sum the amounts for each account type.  The account types are not fixed, will change regularly
}
```

As my note above says, the account fields will not be fixed so I cannot hard code my queries with the names of the account.

Then I would like to have a report detailing the totals of each account.

```
Dell $900
Microsoft $100
Cisco $300
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't see any type in the expected result though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an aggregate function `SUM()` to get the total amount for every account.

```
SELECT  account, SUM(amount) totalAmount
FROM    tableName
WHERE   type = 'inventory'
GROUP   BY account
```

- [MySQL GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks, how do I get the values out of it with a mysql_fetch_array?  Do I have to iterate through it?

Comment: yes because there can be multiple `account`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `GROUP BY` to group your records by `account` and so you can use `SUM()` function to sum all amounts

```
SELECT account, SUM(amount) as total
FROM  table
WHERE type = 'inventory'
GROUP BY account
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `account`,sum(`amount`) FROM `table_name` WHERE `type`='Inventory' group by `account`
```